# How to develop frontend using React js Magento 2.4.4

Tags: javascript, frontend, magento2.4.4, react, react-js

I am stuck on react js integration and development in Magento 2.4.4 so anyone have idea then please share with me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the following:

1] https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ElZ5UtTXpzQ - It is a talk on Integrating a ReactJS frontend in Magento 2

2]https://github.com/Genaker/reactmagento2 - This is a simple module which explains how to add and use React Components with Magento 2